# How to draw dashed border around bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a bitmap of cup image and i want to add dashed border around cup.

Here is what i did try, but it doesn't work :

```
paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5, 10, 15, 20}, 0));

canvas.drawBitmap(cupBitmap, x, y, paint);
```

Comment: You're setting the paint, but you're not drawing any shapes - the bitmap doesn't use your paint.  Maybe figure out the dimensions of your bitmap and draw a rectangle on your canvas.

Comment: Thanks amber for your comment, actually i'm punching my view by given cup bitmap,   i need dashed lines around cup not a rectangle.

Comment: In that case it's a much more difficult problem.  You'll probably have to do some image analysis to figure out where the border of the cup is. Maybe you can find a 3rd party library out there that can do something like this.

Comment: yes i agree, but i was hoping maybe there is a simpler way.., thanks, i will search for some libraries to do this.

Comment: looking for same. did you get answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.